# Pass parameters to Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a Firebase Cloud function to show a push notification to the user. First, I create the notification in the Firestore Database, and then I call a Firebase Cloud Function to send a push notification to the user. The problem is that I don't really know how to pass parameters to the Cloud Function

I call the function like this:

```
import { sendNotificationToUser, sendNotificationToNonUser } from '../../api/PushNotification';

export function createNotification(values, callback) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      ...
      const newNotificationRef = firestore().collection('notifications').doc(notId);

      const newNotification = await firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
        const snapshot = await transaction.get(newNotificationRef);
        const data = snapshot.data();

        return transaction.set(newNotificationRef, {
          ...data,
          ...values,
          id: notId,
          viewed: false
        });
      });

      if (newNotification) {
        if (values.reciever === null) {
          sendNotificationToNonUser(values.title, values.message);
          ...
        } else {
          sendNotificationToUser(values.title, values.message, values.reciever);
          ...
        }
      } else {
        ...
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

Then, on the `PushNotification` doc, I have this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const URL_BASE = 'https://<<MyProjectName>>.cloudfunctions.net';
const Api = axios.create({
  baseURL: URL_BASE
});

export function sendNotificationToNonUser(title, body) {
  Api.get('sendNotificationToNonUser', {
    params: { title, body }
  }).catch(error => { console.log(error.response); });
}

export function sendNotificationToUser(title, body, user) {
  Api.get('sendNotificationToUser', {
    params: { title, body, user }
  }).catch(error => { console.log(error.response); });
}
```

And on my Cloud Functions `index.js`

```
exports.sendNotificationToUser = functions.https.onRequest((data, response) => {
  console.log('Params:');
});
```

How can I pass the params I send from the `PushNotifications` file to the respective Cloud Functions? I'm fairly new to Functions myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `request, response` parameters (data, response in your case) are essentially [Express Request and Response](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_express_request_and_response_objects) objects. You can use  `query` property of request to get those query parameters as shown.

```js
exports.sendNotificationToUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log('Query Params:', request.query);
  // This will log the params objects passed from frontend
});
```

You can also pass information in the request body and then access it by `request.body` in Cloud function, but then you would have to use a POST request.

Comment: `query` for GET and `body` for POST 